# Tensorflow.js predictClass not returning classIndex (NaN)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use "Teachable machine" for own purposes. I want to use it as a boilerplate for training model that classifies images from two classes. Started playing with example from github - https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachable-machine-boilerplate

Changed some stuff to work with local images on nodeJS. Solved some issues and errors that come with it. And now it seems to be working without errors, but it is not predicting anything.

Example from git is pretty easy to understand and I'm using it almost as is (except loading images not from webcam, but from files).

In part right after training each image it outputs this:

```
Processed image cat.10.jpg
{ classIndex: -1, confidences: { '1': NaN } }
```

After coming to another directory:

```
Processed image dog.1.jpg
{ classIndex: -1, confidences: { '1': 0, '2': NaN } }
```

And when it comes to predicting, it outputs this:

```
EXAMPLES:
{ '1': 14, '2': 14 }
PREDICTING
{ classIndex: -1, confidences: { '1': 0, '2': NaN } }
{ classIndex: -1, confidences: { '1': 0, '2': NaN } }
```

Images are resized like at an example to 227x227
Played with bigger train dataset (up to 50 photos), but this makes no sense, example working even from 1 photo.
Tried changing TOPK value - no success.

getOffsets - thats just a function to use only a center 227x227 part of image if it has another size. Also not an issue.

setTimeout - is just lame solution that helped me to run predictions after trainings. Dunno why its not awaiting for it, but it helps. And as far as it says that examples number is correct one - I assume that training is fullfiled.

Do you guys have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const mobilenetModule = require("@tensorflow-models/mobilenet");
const knnClassifier = require("@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier");
const fs = require("fs");
const { createCanvas, Image } = require("canvas");

global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

class NN {
  constructor() {
    this.IMAGE_SIZE = 227;
    this.TOPK = 10;

    this.loadModel();
  }
  async loadModel() {
    this.knn = await knnClassifier.create();
    this.mobilenet = await mobilenetModule.load();

    await this.trainData();
    await this.predictData();
  }

  async predictData() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const exampleCount = this.knn.getClassExampleCount();
      console.log(`EXAMPLES:`);
      console.log(exampleCount);

      console.log("PREDICTING");
      this.predictPath("./dataset/test/a");
    }, 0);
  }

  async trainData() {
    await this.trainPath("./dataset/train/a", 1);
    console.log("TRAINED A");
    await this.trainPath("./dataset/train/b", 2);
    console.log("TRAINED B");
  }

  async trainPath(path, idx) {
    await fs.readdir(path, async (err, imageNames) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {
        const img = await this.processImage(`${path}/${imageNames[i]}`);
        const imgTf = tf.fromPixels(img);

        const inferLocal = img => this.mobilenet.infer(img, "conv_preds");
        const logits = inferLocal(imgTf);

        this.knn.addExample(logits, idx);

        imgTf.dispose();
        if (logits != null) {
          logits.dispose();
        }
        console.log(`Processed image ${imageNames[i]}`);

        // Try to predict after adding
        const numClasses = this.knn.getNumClasses();
        if (numClasses > 0) {
          const prediction = await this.predictImage(
            `${path}/${imageNames[i]}`
          );
          console.log(prediction);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  async predictPath(path) {
    fs.readdir(path, async (err, imageNames) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {
        const prediction = await this.predictImage(`${path}/${imageNames[i]}`);
        console.log(prediction);
      }
    });
  }

  async predictImage(imagePath) {
    const img = await this.processImage(imagePath);
    const imgTf = tf.fromPixels(img);
    const inferLocal = () => this.mobilenet.infer(imgTf, "conv_preds");
    const logits = inferLocal();
    const prediction = await this.knn.predictClass(logits, this.TOPK);
    imgTf.dispose();
    if (logits != null) {
      logits.dispose();
    }
    return prediction;
  }

  async processImage(imagePath) {
    const canvas = createCanvas(this.IMAGE_SIZE, this.IMAGE_SIZE);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = new Image();

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      img.crossOrigin = "";
      img.onload = () => {
        const { x, y } = this.getOffsets(img);
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        resolve(canvas);
      };
    });

    img.src = `${imagePath}`;
    return promise;
  }

  getOffsets(img) {
    let x, y;
    if (Number(img.width) > this.IMAGE_SIZE) {
      x = -(img.width - this.IMAGE_SIZE) / 2;
    } else {
      x = (this.IMAGE_SIZE - img.width) / 2;
    }

    if (Number(img.height) > this.IMAGE_SIZE) {
      y = -(img.height - this.IMAGE_SIZE) / 2;
    } else {
      y = (this.IMAGE_SIZE - img.height) / 2;
    }

    return { x, y };
  }
}

new NN();
```

Comment: Dived into @tensorflow-models/knn-classifier/dist/index.js into KNNClassifier.prototype.calculateTopClass function.
Weird thing. In working example empty array is being created
`var indicesForClasses = [];`
And right after it in a loop it somehow starts holding data:

    for (var i in this.classDatasetMatrices) {
      var num = this.classExampleCount[i];
      if (+i > 0) {
        num += indicesForClasses[+i - 1];
      }
      indicesForClasses.push(num);
    }

Here: `indicesForClasses[+i - 1]` 
Cant understand why. And this one gives NaN's in my nodeJS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daaaamn. Looks like I solved it. We can not user class Indexes from 1 (I used 1 and 2)
They need to be started from 0.

```
await this.trainPath("./dataset/train/a", 0);
await this.trainPath("./dataset/train/b", 1);
```